# Ruby on rails escape unicode characters in search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, html-escape-characters

There is a text saved in database, in the encoded format: 
for example for German letter

> Ü

it stores

> `&Uuml;`

I don't know which method was used to make such a conversion. When executing search, I need to transform character **`Ü`** to **`&Uuml;`** value, how this can be easily done in ROR?
**The following doesn't work:**

```
'Ü'.html_safe -> Ü
ERB::Util.html_escape('Ü') -> Ü
```

Comment: What encoding is set in your DB?

Comment: it doesn't matter. I have in database values `Ü` and `&Uuml;` in different columns. Conversion from `Ü` -> to `&Uuml;` DOES NOT depend on database encoding. It has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Exactly! Knowing your DB columns can and already hold `Ü`, we can rule out ActiveRecord internals. That leaves us with the data input: views and controller. Does data of columns with `&Uuml;` come from user input? If your fix that bit, your will fix the cause of the problem. Otherwise, if you just want a quick fix or a work around look into `htmlentities` gem. It will do the conversion for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [htmlentities](https://rubygems.org/gems/htmlentities) gem.

#### To convert from HTML entity to UTF-8 char:

```
require 'htmlentities'
HTMLEntities.new.decode('&Uuml;')  # => "Ü"
```

#### From UTF-8 to HTML entity:

```
require 'htmlentities'
HTMLEntities.new.encode("Ü", :named)  # => "&Uuml;"
```

Comment: id didn't work. I need convert from `Ü` to `&Uuml;`. So the following solution doesn't work either: `HTMLEntities.new.encode('Ü') -> Ü` **BUT I need `&Uuml;`**

Comment: My bad, I thought you wanted the other way round. Updated my answer.